# How to query objects in array with multiple criteria in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my data

```
// Data 1
{
  name : 111, 
  factors : 
  [
    {name:"f1", value:"dog", unit : "kg"},
    {name:"f2", value:"0"},
    {name: "f3", value:"rain"}
  ]
},
// data2
{
  name : 112, 
  factors : 
  [
    {name:"f1", value:"cat", unit : "g"},
    {name:"f2", value:"13"},
    {name: "f3", value:"rain"}
  ]
}
// more data ...
```

I would like to find the one with `f3=rain`, and `f1=cat`.

I have tried

```
query = {
  factors : {
    $elemMatch : 
       [
          {name: "f1", value:"cat"},
          {name: "f3", value: "rain"}
       ]
},
```

But there is error saying, 
    `Error: error: { "$err" : "$elemMatch needs an Object", "code" : 12517 }`

What should I do to construct that query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) logical query operator

```js
db.collection.find(
    { $and: [
        { "factors": { $elemMatch: { "name": "f1", "value": "cat" } } }, 
        { "factors": { $elemMatch: { "name": "f3", "value": "rain" } } } 
    ]}
)
```

Comment: thx! p.s. do you think it is the optimal data schema for this kind of search? or is it better to make the schema as `[{"f1" : "val12"},{f2: "val22"}]` ?

Comment: Can you please answer this question- 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600862/convert-mongo-query-to-spring-data-query